# How to change the default action for when phone is plugged in to a computer?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, default-applications

When I plugged in my phone to my computer for the first time it gave me a list of options to choose for what to do when it is plugged in. I tapped one of the choices and then mistakenly tapped "Always" instead of "Just Once." I want to choose a different action, but how do I reset it to give me the choices again?

(And yes, I tried going into Settings>Apps>Reset app preferences, but no luck.)

I am running Android 6.0.1, unrooted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When plugged into computer:**

1. Pull down notification bar
2. Click on the USB connection notification
3. Choose either MTP (Recommend for daily use) or Camera mode

Done, you device will still charge, and now you are able to tansfer files between devices

**Side Note:** You are also able to use USB tethering(Under mobile hotspots settings) when connected to share your phone intenet data.

Comment: In sufficiently old versions of android this does not work. As USB connection notification does not show up if you pressed on "always". The solution is to use dev options to change it. once it has been changed once in dev options it will show up again and you can switch it with the "just once" selector

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Settings > Developer Options.
2. Once you enter developer options. Switch to **ON**.
3. Scroll down to **Networking**. You will find  **Select USB configuration**. Select what you want to do with your USB when connected.

---

If you don't see the Developer option, then you can get it by the following steps:

1. Go to Settings
2. Scroll all the way down and tap on ‘About phone.’
3. Now scroll down again and you’ll see an entry labelled ‘Build number.’ Keep on tapping till you see a prompt that says ‘You are now a developer!’

Comment: For the USB configuration, the common case is to select either MTP or PTP for a PC to be able to detect the Android device.