# Can I make the USB connection default to file transfer only for my computer?

Tags: file-transfer, android-10

Every time I plug in my phone to my computer, it defaults to only charging. I have to open the phone notification to switch to file transfer mode. Is there a way to tell it to remember to use file transfer mode when connecting to my laptop? Or to change the default when connecting to my laptop?

I know that it is possible to [change the default](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/152156/193324) for all connections. However, I would prefer if it only changed the default when connecting with my laptop. I'm also uncomfortable that I would need to dig inside the developer settings to change the default.

If it matters, my phone has Android 10 (Q).

Comment: Your phone can not identify which computer it is connected to, therefore no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phone can not identify which computer it is connected to, USB an MTP protocol does not include something that could identify a host computer.

There is a feature for [USB-C authentication](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/2019-01/USB-IF_USB%20Type-C%20Authentication%20Program%20Press%20Release_FINAL_20181227.pdf) [planned](https://www.zdnet.com/article/usb-type-c-gets-authentication-to-protect-against-malicious-devices/) but I have never heard that it is already supported by a device and if I understand it correctly it should allow to identify a device type or a device class, not an individual device or computer:

> USB Type-C Authentication empowers host systems to protect against
> non-compliant USB chargers and to mitigate risks from malicious
> firmware/hardware in USB devices attempting to exploit a USB
> connection. Using this protocol, host systems can confirm the
> authenticity of a USB device, USB cable or USB charger, including such
> product aspects as the capabilities and certification status.

Therefore the answer is no, with pure MTP and/or USB this is impossible.

However the other Android USB protocol Android Debug Bridge (ADB) supports authentication. The host computer automatically creates a RSA key pair you is used for authentication. The whole process is similar to SSH where you can trust a computer based on it's key pair when you connect to it the first time.

Hence you should enable developer options and ADB on your device and use adb based tools instead.

Note that if you should get an update to Android 11 there is a feature that automatically removes adb authorizations after a certain time. This option can also be found in developer options. In my opinion it is recommended to disable feature.